# why my mysql DB can read without update or insert data in Rails 4?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Guy I got something strange in my project

Now I got old ruby on rails project to develop some notes in it after I activate the commands

```
bundle
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
rails s
```

First the application asked me to install mysql2 0.3.14 and after installed it I got the error

```
log writing faild. invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

and I solved it by added the `#encoding: utf-8`  in every first line in the project models

and finally now I can open my project well  **but**
I found when I read data from my DB it work well when tried to insert or update any data from my MYSQL DB nothing happen with me !!!!! I thought that my DB user only take permissions to read only from the DB  but after checked the user permissions I found it takes all the permissions

So can any one explain to me why I go this issue ????

This is a simple code to insert into my MYSQL DB
**the View code**

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :icon %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :icon %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**controller code**

```
def create
  #Just test to insert fixed data to my DB but also not insert any thing  
  @category =Category.new(:title => 'eeeee', :icon_file_name => 'xxx', :slug => 'sug')
  #@category =Category.new(:title => params[:title], :icon_file_name => params[:icon], :slug => params[:slug])

 #@category = Category.new(category_params) 
 respond_to do |format|
   if @category.save
     format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @category }
   else
     format.html { render action: 'new' }
     format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
end
```

**Note: I'm using Windows 7**

Comment: Could you explain in more details what's happening. No new record in db? Are you redirected to show action or stays on the form? Any error message?

Comment: No error message 
this case makes me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't sanitize your params. In Rails 4 strong parameters have been introduced in order to increase security of untrusted sources posting data to your database.

So in your controller you have to add a private method (if you generated it with scaffolding it should be already present) to say which parameters to accept.

in your case should be something like

```
def category_params
 params.require(:category).permit(:title, :icon_file_name, :slug, :whatever_other_param_you_need)

end
```

Read more here http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: HI sissy , yes i know and this is already i was do  but still got the same issue     
def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:title, :icon, :slug)
end

Comment: Sissy, if the problem in the prams  so why when i set fixed data in my code it not worked with me ??

Comment: maybe it's a typo, but have you checked the proper names of your params? in the code you posted is written icon_file_name but here you wrote only icon. 
What about your log file when you're saving? is it saying begin---commit? or there's a begin--rollback?
just make this try: just after Category.new, add @category.valid? and @category.errors just to see if it is a valid object.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your last comment. I'm just guessing cause the information you provided are not enough, so i thought it was a params problem. Try to take a closer look to your log to see what the server is doing.